# base64 conversion in context with curl

Tags: json, curl, signals

I would like to send a message and attachment via **signal-cli**.

I successfully set up docker a container by **bbernhard/signal-cli-rest-api**.
Normal message sending with curl-statement works fine and statement looks like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"message\": \"Hello World!\", \"number\": \"+490000000\", \"recipients\": [\"+4900000000"]}' 'http://localhost:48080/v2/send'
```

The message will be sent to one recipient or many. Also working for a group by groupID.

Question: How to add an attachment like a JPG?

If I add `\"base64_attachments\": [\"${ENCODED_IMAGE}")\"]` to the statement, then i get the error message `{"error":"Couldn't process request - invalid request"}`

Full bash script looks like :

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_FILE="/path/to/file/IMG_5098.JPG"

TMPFILE=$(mktemp)

base64 "${INPUT_FILE}" --wrap=0 > "${TMPFILE}"

ENCODED_IMAGE=$(cat "${TMPFILE}")

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"message\": \"Hello World!\", \"base64_attachments\": [\"${ENCODED_IMAGE}")\"], \"number\": \"+4900000\", \"recipients\": [\"+4900000000\"]}' 'http://localhost:48080/v2/send'

rm "${TMPFILE}"
```

I expected the image send as well as the message

Comment: I ran the `bbernhard/signal-cli-rest-api` by docker compose with this [yml](https://github.com/bbernhard/signal-cli-rest-api) file. and try to registry phone number with `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://127.0.0.1:9922/v1/register/+431212131491291'` But all modes (json-rpc, native, normal) makes errors (This endpoint is not supported in JSON-RCP mode., Failed to load native library:sqlite-3.40.0., Failed to register: [413] Rate limit exceeded: 413) How to registry phone number? If not registry can't test v2/send API

Comment: I did not register a new User. You can connect your already existing User by generating a QR Code and then couple the mobile device with it.

Comment: Meanwhile I got the base64 running. Now I receive the Message that the Argument list is too long.
It seems that the curl Statement is not able to proceed the base64 string. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I got it!

I encode the jpeg by: TMPFILE="$(base64 $INPUT_FILE)"

The new curl-statement works as it sends a message as well as a picture:

echo '{"message": "'"${meintext}"'", "base64_attachments": ["'"${TMPFILE}"'"], "number": "+49000000", "recipients": ["+490000000000000"]}' | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- 'http://ip_:port/v2/send'

Comment: Good job!,happy to hear you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Here's how I managed to send a file through the Docker Terminal:

```
TMPFILE="$(base64 SignalsPictures/flow.png)" && echo '{"message": "Test message", "base64_attachments": ["'"$TMPFILE"'"], "number": "+123456789012", "recipients": ["group.e..0="]}' | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- 'http://localhost:8080/v2/send'
```